# Option ERROR with Babel in React-Native-App(Expo)

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

While launching the simulator with 'expo start' I get the following error:

[BABEL] /Users/user/Documents/projects/ProArea/nanny-tribe/src/index.native.js: Unknown option: .name. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.

The error appeared after updating the packages, since the project was outdated. I've tried changing imports from 'react-native-dotenv' to '@env' but it doesn't work.

My package.json is as follows:

```
   {
   "name": "nanny-tribe",
   "version": "1.0.40",
   "private": true,
   "main": "./src/index.native.js",
   "license": "UNLICENSED",
   "engines": {
   "node": ">= 8.12.0"
    },
   "scripts": {
   "start": "node index.js",
   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
     
   "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
   "eject": "react-app eject",
   "native-start": "rndebugger-open --open && expo-cli start --lan -c",
   "native-eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
   "native-storybook": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail -raw\"yarn native- 
  start\" \"storybook start -p 7007\"",
   "android": "expo-cli android",
   "ios": "expo start --ios",
   "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9009 -s public",
   "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
   "dev": "HTTPS=true concurrently --kill-others-on-fail --raw \"nodemon --watch\" 
  \"FORCE_COLOR=true react-app-rewired start | cat\"",
   "api": "nodemon --watch",
     
    "sequelize": "dotenv sequelize",
    "sequelize-cli": "^5.3.0",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate",
    "prestorybook": "rnstl",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "expo-build": "expo build:ios",
    "upload": "dotenv -- expo upload:ios --latest",
    "upload:android": "expo upload:android --key ./api-8146341486491315803-445540- 97418dee0cde.json"
 },
    "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.15.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.14.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.5",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.983.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.3",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "8.4.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "connected-react-router": "6.9.1",
    "core-js": "^3.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.4.0",
   "expo-av": "~9.2.3",
   "expo-constants": "~11.0.2",
   "expo-facebook": "~11.3.1",
   "expo-file-system": "~11.1.3",
   "expo-font": "~9.2.1",
   "expo-image-picker": "~10.2.3",
   "expo-linear-gradient": "~9.2.0",
   "expo-permissions": "~12.1.1",
   "expo-secure-store": "~10.2.0",
   "expo-server-sdk": "^3.6.0",
   "expo-web-browser": "~9.2.0",
   "express": "^4.17.1",     
  "faker":"Marak/faker.js#d3ce6f1a2a9359574e7f31f14d4901648047c45a",
   "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
   "form-data": "^4.0.0",
   "geolib": "^3.3.1",
   "history": "^5.0.1",
   "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.1",
   "igniculus": "^1.5.0",
   "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
   "lodash": "^4.17.21",
   "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
   "luxon": "^2.0.2",
   "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
   "morgan": "^1.10.0",
   "multer": "^1.4.3",
   "native-base": "^3.1.0",
   "node-fetch": "^3.0.0",
   "passport": "^0.4.1",
   "passport-custom": "^1.1.1",
   "passport-facebook-token": "^4.0.0",
   "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
   "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
   "passport-oauth": "^1.0.0",
   "pg": "^8.7.1",
   "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
   "qs": "^6.10.1",
   "react": "17.0.2",
   "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",
   "react-art": "^17.0.2",
   "react-burger-menu": "^3.0.6",
   "react-dom": "17.0.2",
   "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
   "react-native": "0.65.1",
   "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
   "react-native-app-link": "^1.0.1",
   "react-native-calendars": "^1.1266.0",
   "react-native-confetti": "^0.1.0",
   "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.1.0",
   "react-native-dotenv": "^3.2.0",
   "react-native-dropdownalert": "^4.3.0",
   "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
   "react-native-facebook-login": "^1.6.2",
   "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.3",
   "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
   "react-native-global-props": "^1.1.5",
   "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
   "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
   "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^11.0.0",
   "react-native-progress-bar-animated": "^1.0.6",
   "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
   "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
   "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
   "react-native-screens": "3.4.0",
   "react-native-sectioned-multi-select": "^0.8.1",
   "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
   "react-native-style-tachyons": "^4.2.0",
   "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
   "react-native-svg-image": "^2.0.1",
   "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
   "react-native-web": "~0.17.1",
   "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
   "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.1",
   "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
   "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.1",
   "react-redux": "7.2.5",
   "react-router": "^5.2.1",
   "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
   "react-router-native": "^5.2.1",
   "react-router-navigation": "^2.0.0-alpha.10",
   "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
   "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
   "redux": "^4.1.1",
   "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
   "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
   "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
   "schedule": "0.5.0",
   "sequelize": "^6.6.5",
   "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",
   "storybook": "^6.3.8",
   "stripe": "^8.174.0",
   "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
   "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
     "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
     "uuid": "^8.3.2"
 },
   "browserslist": {
   "development": [
     "last 2 chrome versions",
     "last 2 firefox versions",
     "last 2 edge versions"
   ],
   "production": [
     ">1%",
     "last 4 versions",
     "Firefox ESR",
     "not ie < 11"
   ]
 },
 "config": {
   "react-native-storybook-loader": {
     "searchDir": [
       "./src"
     ],
     "pattern": "**/story.native.js",
     "outputFile": "./storybook/storyLoader.js"
   }
 },
 "proxy": "https://localhost:8080",
 "devDependencies": {
   "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.14.5",
   "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.8",
   "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.8",
   "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.3.8",
   "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^6.3.8",
   "@storybook/addons": "^6.3.8",
   "@storybook/react": "^6.3.8",
   "@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.25",
   "concurrently": "^6.2.1",
   "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
   "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
   "dotenv-cli": "^4.0.0",
   "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
   "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
   "expo": "^42.0.3",
   "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
   "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
   "react-native-debugger-open": "^0.3.25",
   "react-native-storybook-loader": "^2.0.4"
 }
}
```

babel.config.js :

```
    const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
      include: [
        path.resolve('src'),
        path.resolve('.storybook'),
        path.resolve('node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme'),
        path.resolve('node_modules/react-native-easy-grid'),
        path.resolve('node_modules/react-native-drawer'),
    path.resolve('node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'),
    path.resolve('node_modules/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'),
    path.resolve('node_modules/react-native-calendars'),
    path.resolve('node_modules/react-native-gifted-chat'),
    path.resolve('node_modules/react-native-parsed-text'),
    path.resolve('node_modules/react-native-lightbox'),
    path.resolve('node_modules/react-native-video'),
    path.resolve('node_modules/@expo/react-native-action-sheet'),
    path.resolve('node_modules/native-base/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'),
    path.resolve('node_modules/react-native-sectioned-multi-select')
  ],
        plugins: [
       'react-native-web',
       '@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread',
       ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { 'loose': false }]
       ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
        "moduleName": "@env",
        "path": ".env",
        "blacklist": null,
        "whitelist": null,
        "safe": false,
        "allowUndefined": true
      }]
    ],
     presets: [
      [
        '@babel/env',
        'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
        {
          targets: {
            browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions']
          },
          modules: 'commonjs'
        }
      ],
      '@babel/preset-flow',
      '@babel/preset-react'
    ]
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename `@babel/env` to `@babel/preset-env` or remove it altogether from your `presets` as it is unnecessary for `react-native-dotenv`. Source: I'm the `react-native-dotenv` maintainer.